# C# Selenium Reading the complete data from a Database (SQL Server)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, selenium

I'm using Selenium in C# to retreive the data from a database with 2 rows of data with the columns; UserID, UserName, and Password. I'm just getting the UserName and Password from the rows to enter into the webpage. I'm able to return the first row of my Database but I'm trying to have my code run as many times as I have rows of data in my database. Here is my code so far.

```
public class DBConnection
    {
    static SqlConnection con;
    static SqlDataReader dr;
    static SqlCommand cmd;

      public static void DBConnect()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_Table"];
        String connectionString = connection.ConnectionString;
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName, Password FROM dbo.Users", con);

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string username = dr["UserName"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(username);
                string password = dr["Password"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(password);

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                AUT.Browser.FindElement(By.Name("username")).Click();
                AUT.Browser.FindElement(By.Name("username")).Click();
                AUT.Browser.FindElement(By.Name("username")).Clear();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                AUT.Browser.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys(username);
                AUT.Browser.FindElement(By.Name("password")).Clear();
                AUT.Browser.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys(password);
                AUT.Browser.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error" + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This code retrieves the correct data from the Database but it doesn't get the multiple rows of data. It only grabs the first row and then it tries to overwrite the data using the second row of data from the first row after the webpage reaches the next page which causes my Test to fail. I'm trying to have it reopen the webpage and reenter another userName and Password from the 2 or more rows of data I have in my database after it opens and reads the first row of data. My guess is that I would have to close and reopen the connection in my while loop, but I've tried that and I'm having no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/

Comment: Then have a separated function to open a new page inside the Loop and send the Login/password there to a new page each time.

Comment: your while loop is fine.  But why are you entering a 2nd user before you are done testing the first?

Comment: @NeilN I have multiple rows of data, the problem I'm having is that I'm finished with the first test and want to open a new test with the second row of data but it tries to overwrite the first row's data when it hits the next page instead of restarting the whole process. I'm not trying to enter the 2nd user before I'm done testing the first.

Comment: Right, I get that... but you don't have any code to return to the start of the test. You just submit the form and start entering the next record.  You need to add at least two steps: 1) confirm that the login worked, 2) return to the start of the test.  Then you can enter the next record

Comment: @NeilN Oh, ok. I see. Wouldn't closing and the opening the DB connection do that? I'm sorry if I'm asking noobish questions, this is my first time working with DBs in selenium.

Comment: No, the DB has nothing to do with the front end.

Comment: Ok, so I would need to make another call to my <openWebpage> call after I call my DB function? But that would just reread the first row of data if that's the case. I would need something like <TestContext.DataRow> Thats how I read the rows from an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: no, the two steps I suggested you add are WITHIN the loop.

Comment: Ok, I'm confirming that the login works, also I've tried adding "return;" to my code within my while loop and try- catch but still no luck. Also thank you very much for the responses.

Comment: "return" in C# exits the function.  That is not what you want.  You need to call the relative selenium function to load the login page

Comment: @NeilN Got it! Thank you. I had to add my call to go to the webpage within the while loop like you stated and it read both rows and opened a new webpage like I wanted it to. Thank you very much for you help. Could you put your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres is the pseudo code for what you want to do:

1. Load data
2. Loop over data:

   a. Enter username

   b. enter password

   c. press enter

   d. wait for page load

   e. confirm login worked

   f. load login page again.

add in the missing steps and you should be good to go.